# How to get Calc in French

Tags: libreoffice, internationalization

I am trying to get Libreoffice calc in French to get the French function names. I tried to install the language package but I think I don't have the right version. My version of Calc is 3.5. Tools - options - libreoffice doesn't offer online updates.
Do I need to update Calc first or can I just somehow install the French version?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you install the `libreoffice-l10n-fr` package?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

To get localized function names in LibreOffice Calc, follow the 4 steps below:

1. Open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libreoffice-l10n-fr
   ```

   It will install the French language package
2. Set both **User Interface** and **Locale settings** to *French (France)*:

   [image]
3. Ensure that the **Use English function names** checkbox is disabled:

   [image]
4. Finally restart LibreOffice to enable French function names.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that "Use English function names" toggle. Having to remember function names both in English and Portuguese slows my productivity quite a bit sometimes. Made my day! BTW, Excel doesn't have that, does it?

Comment: I'm not the OP, just someone who's also posted an answer to the question. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can change LibreOffice's default language at the Options (Tools > Options) window. Expand the "Language Settings" menu and under "Language" set the language for both the user interface and the regional/locale settings (which influences the decimal separator, data format, etc.).  Here's an example:

[image]